# Retrieving all values of json object into array list

Tags: android, json

I have a json object as below

```
{
"Book1":{"Title1":"Cost1","Title2":"Cost2"}, 
"Book2":{"Title3 ":"Cost3"},
"Book3":{"Title4 ":"Cost4","Title5 ":"Cost5"},
"Book4":{"Title6":"Cost6","Title7”:”Cost7","Title8”:”Cost8"}
}
```

I want to retrieve all the values of "Titles" without any keywords i.e I would like to have {Title1,Title2,Title3,Title4,...} in an array.

Below is my code to retrieve based on Book name but now I need to retrieve all the values

```
    List<String> books=new ArrayList<String >();
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAssetArea());
        JSONObject bookJson = obj.getJSONObject("Book1");


        Iterator<String> keys= bookJson.keys();
        do
        {
            String keyValue = (String)keys.next();
            JSONArray specTitle = obj.getJSONArray(keyValue);
            for (int i = 0; i < specTitle.length(); i++) {
               books.add(specTitle.get(i).toString());
            }

        }while(keys.hasNext());


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am not getting how to get with out passing key values to json object .
Kindly help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually this is not valid Json Array https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: you dont have Json Array .. right?? you only had json Object.. Then Why You Use Json Array Code??

Comment: This is a part of json object I am using to retrieve the values the above code I am using to get the Title and cost of the book

Comment: the JSON sample you have given is json object, not json array

Comment: @samz22 please check my answer is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This is Working

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAssetArea());

 List<String> books=new ArrayList<String >();
        try {
               Iterator  iteratorObj = jsonObject.keys();
            while (iteratorObj.hasNext())
            {
                String getJsonObj = (String)iteratorObj.next();
                System.out.println("Book No.: "   + "------>" + getJsonObj);

                JSONObject jo_inside = jsonObject.getJSONObject(getJsonObj);
                //JSONObject jo_inside = new JSONObject((String) iteratorObj.next());

                Iterator<String> keys = jo_inside.keys();
                while (keys.hasNext())
                {
                    String key = keys.next();
                    String value = jo_inside.getString(key);
                    Log.v("Book Title key", key);
                    Log.v("Book Name value", value);
                    books.add(jo_inside.getString(key));
                }

            }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**

Your **GIVEN** **`Json`** is not Valid.

- **`Book1,Book2..`** are **`DYNAMIC/UNKNOWN`**.
- Use **`Iterator`** in this way.

Try this way,

```
JSONObject jOBJ= new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAssetArea());
              Iterator  iteratorObj = jOBJ.keys();
               while (iteratorObj.hasNext())
                {
                   String getJsonObj = (String)iteratorObj.next();
                   System.out.println("Key: " + Key + "------>" + getJsonObj); // print Book1,Book2..
                  // Now your work

                }
```

Comment: I have more than 1000 json objects so it will be iterating more than 1000 times and app crashes.I have used just a part of json

Comment: Sorry my mistake It didn't crash but taking very long time to iterate more than 1000 values so the app opens very late  I require the values of only title but the log cat is showing all the values as below                                               {“Android”:{"Hello Android”:”230.0","Progamming Android”:”350.0”},"Java":{"Thinking in Java”:"200","Learn Java":"250"},     this is part of log cat.Here I require only the name of books

Comment: @samz22 too much data that's why slow.

Comment: how to get the values of only books.this I need for autocomplete textview

Comment: @samz22 check your key `value.contains("Book")` then your work

Comment: I don't have keyword "Book" in my json {“Android”:{"Hello Android”:”230.0","Progamming Android”:”350.0”},"Java":{"Thinking in Java”:"200","Learn Java":"250"},

Comment: @samz22 in your main question have. Try my logic.hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse this

```
{
"Book1":{"Title1":"Cost1","Title2":"Cost2"}, 
"Book2":{"Title3 ":"Cost3"},
"Book3":{"Title4 ":"Cost4","Title5 ":"Cost5"},
"Book4":{"Title6":"Cost6","Title7”:”Cost7","Title8”:”Cost8"}
}
```

you can use this code to parse the json object,

```
List<String> books = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAssetArea());
        JSONObject bookJson, innerObject;
        Iterator<String> keys = obj.keys();
        do {
            String keyValue = (String) keys.next();
            if (obj.get(keyValue) instanceof JSONObject) {
                bookJson = obj.getJSONObject(keyValue);
                Iterator<?> innerKeys = bookJson.keys();
                while (innerKeys.hasNext()) {
                    String innerKey = (String) innerKeys.next();
                    innerObject = bookJson.getJSONObject(innerKey);
                    books.add(innerObject.getString(innerKey));
                }
            }
        } while (keys.hasNext());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I won't be passing any Book1 values JSONObject bookJson = obj.getJSONObject("Book1"); would want to retrieve entire titles of the books in the whole json